# How to clear DIV and add new content in while loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I need to clear the `<div>` and insert new content I get from the database after each while loop  in php. Can someone help me out with this problem?
Also I need to sleep in the loop for about 10 sec.

I am using PHP for the while loop.

The general flow is like this -

```
while() {
  read from database;
  sleep;
  clear div;      ///I nead help here;
  Add content to div ///I need help here
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you expect to get PHP to sleep every ten seconds? Sounds like you need JavaScript on the client-size to update the `<div>` on a regular basis.

Comment: People in stackoverflow are, sometimes, intolerant. From what I understand you want your page div to be refreshed after each 10 seconds. You can't do that in php. You only can do that using javascript and ajax (and some php to get information in the database).

    `function read () {
        // get information from database using ajax
        var element = document.getElementById("elementid");
        element.innerHTML = "";
        element.innerHTML = "html"; // formated html using what you got in the database
    };

setInterval(read, 10000);`

Comment: @Blazemonger // sleep for 10 seconds - sleep(10); (this obviously would not work in the way he intended however). But yes client side is what you want user1459032

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to clear - `$("div").empty();`

to fill  - `$("div").html(your_ajax_response);`

Comment: That's jQuery. Isn't OP asking about PHP? (Hard to tell with pseudocode in question)

Comment: Thank you...But I am unable to use it in the while loop with php....Can you give me a snippet...

Comment: @palintropos indeed hard to tell, but he included `jquery` and `javascript` in the tags

Comment: @palintropos They are, but what they want to do isn't possible using PHP alone. Just because they think they want/need to use a certain language/technology, it doesn't mean they actually do.

Comment: You can't manipulate your `div` content with PHP - it has to be JS. What you have to do is send an ajax call every 10 seconds to your PHP script and show the response upon success. For reference look here, for example - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/